# How to access the BIOS in my brand new HP Laptop with runs FreeDOS?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, freedos

I've just bought a HP Laptop 255 G2 with AMD quad-core processor which runs FreeDOS and I can' access the BIOS with any command that I know (I tried F1,F2,F8,F9,F10,F12 and Del) but it didn't work!
It just show me a boot menu at the start and I got two options: FreeDOS and HP Documents.
After I entered in FreeDOS,it showed me a terminal and I couldn't do anything with it (maybe because I don't know the commands).
So...How should I install another operating system from a DVD?

Comment: I think it's F10 but you need to repeatedly press it from the moment you press the power button...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documented procedure is to press ESCAPE immediatly followed by F10 (see: http://www.manualslib.com/manual/608043/Hp-15.html?page=115#manual). However, pressing ESCAPE several time will bring up a small menu where you can select what to do next. This might be more comfortable.